# Splines in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, spline

is there a class for connecting points by a spline in flex resp. actionscript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Degrafa project provides classes for this sort of thing - it is Flex-centric however.

Degrafa can be found here -> www.degrafa.org.

If you go to the docs http://www.degrafa.org/docs/ you can scroll right to the BezierSpline for an example class.

Comment: do you know if I can use it with FlashDevelop or do I need the Flexbuilder? FlashDevelop just gave me this message as I tried to insert a tag.

col: 19 Error: The prefix "degrafa" for element "degrafa:filters" is not bound.

Comment: Ok just found the learning guide for degrafa, really nice, many thanks therefor